# Javascript .call() usage. One working case, one not. What's the diff?

Tags: javascript, this, call, apply

I'm confused at the difference in these usage cases:

```
   // CASE 1: Two separate attempts, neither work (see comments)

    var circle = new google.maps.Circle({ 
          // and then a bunch of properties, all work fine. Including this to show you 
          // where the variable I'm trying to use in call() came from
    });

    circle.initListeners = function(){
         this.addListener('mouseover', function(){

              // Works if circle is named explicitly in explodeView (see code below), 
              // doesn't work with .call(circle) here, this.setRadius() in explodeView   
              explodeView().call(circle);

              // Both work fine
              this.infoWindow.setPosition(this.getBounds().getNorthEast());
              this.infoWindow.open(map);

              // Works with circle.getCenter, not with .call(circle) and this
              this.timer = setInterval(function(){
                  map.panTo(this.getCenter());
              }, 1000).call(circle)

               // Works with circle.setRadius, not with this.setRadius
               function explodeView(){
                   var radiusExtender = ((300 - tweet.stats.reach) + 1) / 60;
                   radiusExtender > 1.15 ? this.setRadius(radiusExtender * radius) : this.setRadius(radius * 1.15);
               }  
          });
      });
```

Compare this with the following use of `.call()`, which I implemented after getting a `"this does not have method ._togCircVis(...)"` error when invoking the function without `.call(map)`:

```
   // CASE 2: Works

   // Call to function I added to circle prototype
   map._togCircVis.call(map)

   // Successfully receives map and executes correctly
   google.maps.Map.prototype._togCircVis = function(){
      this.circles.forEach(function(circle){
        circle.getMap() != null ? circle.setMap(null) : circle.setMap(map);
      })
    }
```

When I try the code in Case 1, I get the same `"this does not have method "` error as I did before adding `.call(map)` to Case 2. Same thing when I try .apply() instead of .call() (a Hail Mary debug attempt). I get why the addition to Case 2 makes it work, as it clarifies for the invoked function that I'm talking about the `map` object, not the window object, when I use `this` for variable assignment. But, why doesn't it work with the above cases? MDN articles helped me get to using .call(map), but did not clear up this other use for me. Thanks!

Comment: `setInterval` does not return a function, so you cannot `.call` it.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`explodeView().call(circle);` here you are calling explodeView normally (without call) and then trying to call `call` on the value it returned (`undefined`). Instead you should write `explodeView.call( circle )`. You have a very similar problem here:

```
setInterval(function(){
    map.panTo(this.getCenter());
}, 1000).call(circle);
```

You are trying to call `call` on an object that isn't a function. Before it was `undefined`, this time it is a number ([setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) returns a number). You could use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) like this to achieve what you want:

```
setInterval(function(){
    map.panTo(this.getCenter());
}.bind(circle), 1000);
```

Comment: Or just use `circle.getCenter`, instead of using `this` and `bind` unnecessarily

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks! I appreciate the differentiation between cases.

Comment: @Bergi -- Just making sure I understand the applications of each, new to javascript and trying to learn as thoroughly as possible. Thanks, though! I agree the simplicity is a plus, will probably be what I keep